# How to join two tables and order by a third table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, join, relational-database

So I have three tables, however my SQL JOIN statement continuously returns the same result for some reason instead of returning all rows and ordering them by the third.

This statement correctly works and returns the gName and uName as expected:

`SELECT
    rpg.name AS gName, 
    u.username AS uName
FROM 
    roleplay_gangs rpg
LEFT JOIN 
    users u on u.id = rpg.owner_id`

However when I try to select and order it by a field within the third table, the result isn't as expected for some reason. I've looked around for a while and attempted multiple times but none seem to work for me, never had to join more than 2 tables and order at the same time.

So... I attempted to try it with the third table:

`SELECT
    rpg.name AS gName, 
    u.username AS uName,
    COUNT(rpgt.gang_id) AS gCount
FROM 
    roleplay_gangs rpg
LEFT JOIN
    users u on u.id = rpg.owner_id
LEFT JOIN
    roleplay_gangs_turfs rpgt on rpg.id = rpgt.gang_id
ORDER BY gCount`

result:

```
gName | uName | gCount
-----------------------
test  | hello | 2
```

expected:

```
gName | uName | gCount
-----------------------
test  | hello | 2
zmaj  | hello | 0
thir  | ajtea | 0
```

Any help is appreciated, able to post more details on request if required.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `joins`, but when you're using aggregation, you need to include the `group by` clause.  I suspect you're using `mysql` and thus the query is returning a random row (it shouldn't do this imo).

Comment: It still only returned one result rather than the three, I was thinking it may be because the gCount for two of the results aren't present or null as they have not yet got any.

Comment: Adding `GROUP BY rpgt.gang_id` returns two results now instead of the three. The ones which share the uName are both showing, the ajtea row isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields you are selecting that you want to be unique in the results should be included in the `group by` clause when using aggregation such as `count`:

```
SELECT
    rpg.name AS gName, 
    u.username AS uName,
    COUNT(rpgt.gang_id) AS gCount
FROM 
    roleplay_gangs rpg
LEFT JOIN
    users u on u.id = rpg.owner_id
LEFT JOIN
    roleplay_gangs_turfs rpgt on rpg.id = rpgt.gang_id
GROUP BY
    rpg.name, 
    u.username 
ORDER BY gCount
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect however I don't quite understand what you are explaining as I've never come across those terms before. Anyway I could understand what you are explaining to me, some kind of manual or short clip related to unique results/group by/aggregation?